# WPF: is it possible to call function from XAML

Tags: wpf

So i have this `Calss Member` that calculate my actual file size:

```
private static ulong _fileSize;

public static ulong FileSize
{
    get { return _fileSize; }
    set
    {
        _fileSize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

My class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
XAML
```

And then my `UI` is updated automatically:

```
<Label
Content="{Binding Path=(my:MyClass.FileSize)}"
ContentStringFormat="{}{0:0.##}"/>
```

But my problem is that my `file size` is in `bytes` and i want to convert it to human readable format for example `2.34MB` or `1.01 GB` so i have this function:

```
static string SizeSuffix(ulong buyes, int decimalPlaces = 0)
{
    string[] SizeSuffixes = { "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB" };
    if (buyes > 0)
    {
        var mag = (int)Math.Max(0, Math.Log(buyes, 1024));
        var adjustedSize = Math.Round(buyes / Math.Pow(1024, mag), decimalPlaces);
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", adjustedSize, SizeSuffixes[mag]);
    }

    else
        return "0";
}
```

So my question is: is it possible to call `SizeSuffix` function from `XAML` ?

Comment: Use a [Binding Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using a Converter, to convert your original file size bytes into your desired string using your convert function, but is probably a better way to expose a property with this (convert) value.

In this scenario it's useful to create another property in your View Model (Data Context), that will convert to a human readable file size, since it's a read-only property that it be updated in your Model.

Code:

```
private static ulong _fileSize;
private string _fileSizeString;

public static ulong FileSize
{
    get { return _fileSize; }
    set
    {
        _fileSize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FileSize");
        OnPropertyChanged("FileSizeString");
    }
}
public string FileSizeString { get { return SizeSuffix(FileSize); }}
```

Then, in your xaml you just bind your label to FileSizeString property.